# due to versus as a result of

Tags: phrase-usage

According to the answer key of a SAT preparation book I'm studying, there is an error in the sentence

> By the time the bank guard closed the doors, a riot had erupted **due to** the long lines and shortage of tellers.

and it should be changed to

> By the time the bank guard closed the doors, a riot had erupted **as a result of** the long lines and shortage of tellers.

I disagree with this. Why is the first sentence unacceptable?

Comment: Both look fine to me. Maybe it's a mistake (SAT prep books can have mistakes!) or maybe someone more knowledgeable than I will have an answer.

Comment: True, and the [SAT itself](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/001863.html) sometimes has mistakes, as well.

Comment: By the time the bank guard closed the doors, a riot had erupted BECAUSE OF the long lines and shortage of tellers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

19th-century stylists held that *due* is an adjective and that *due to X* phrases should be employed only as

- a postposed modifier, as in *A riot due to long lines erupted*, or
- a predicate adjective, as in *The riot was due to long lines*.

Actual on-the-ground usage has long since transformed *due to* into a preposition equivalent to *because of*, and you may safely ignore this ‘rule’ in all circumstances **except one**:

> When you're taking a test of your knowledge of English, assume your examiner follows the old rule: use *due* only as an adjective, and treat any other use as incorrect.

It’s stupid, but it’s a fact. As the poet Schiller wrote:

> Against stupidity the gods themselves struggle in vain.

Comment: Now I know from where Isaac Asimov took the title of the three parts of his novel, [_The God Themselves_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gods_Themselves). `:)`

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand the exception. Are you saying that if the sentence is about an English test (ex. the SAT as mentioned above), *due to* cannot mean *because of*? So *Due to my unwillingness to study, I failed the writing portion of the SAT* would be incorrect? (Forgive me if I'm misinterpreting... Cough medicine doesn't exactly improve my reading comprehension :))

Comment: @WendiKidd Ambiguity noted and corrected.

Comment: This reminds me of an anecdote where a professor at our school once told the students, "Never use _since_ to mean _because_, as in, 'The crops grew well since the weather was so temperate'." Why not? Why do teachers have axes to grind against the [dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/since)?

Comment: @J.R. The professor's example is to the point, but his rule is bad: it should be "Be careful not to use *since* to mean *because* when it may be read as *in the time span beginning at X and extending to reference time*.

Comment: I ignore that rule, since it's quite easy to come up with sentences that would never be construed that way :-)

Answer (score 0):

The reason "due to" should be replaced with " as a result of" can be found here in the below mentioned links :

1) http://www.englishforums.com/English/DueBecauseResultOf/bhbhp/post.htm

2) http://www.englishforums.com/English/DueTo/nrld/post.htm

Comment: I'm sure providing links to external site except for online dictionaries is a bad idea.

Comment: Yes. It is a bad idea. Links deteriorate and disappear over time. CV in general and ELL in particular aim to be here for a while!