# "Due to" vs. "As a result of " in this sentence

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

I wrote :

> English language learners (ELL) are likely to experience more difficulties **as a result of** problems in auditory discrimination of speech sounds.

But I feel it may sound better with

> English language learners (ELL) are likely to experience more difficulties **due to** problems in auditory discrimination of speech sounds.

Am I right? As I found in this question [due to versus as a result of](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/10420/due-to-versus-as-a-result-of?lq=1) due to could be traditionally used as adjective, and here it may play the adjective role of *difficulties*. Is there any difference here?

Comment: They mean the same thing.  "*Due to* this question, I'm writing this comment."  "*As a result of* this question, I'm writing this comment."  They both basically mean "because of."

Comment: @BenjaminHarman is right, they mean exactly the same thing. And they're both correct! Use whichever one you prefer.