# Formal way of asking "Don't we need to?"

Tags: phrase-request, formality

What phrase should be used in place of "Don't we need to" in a formal letter?

Example situation: Boss sent a mail indicating that some data is to be updated in chart A. The reply is like "I have updated the data in chart A. Don't we need to update it in chart B too?"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [due to versus as a result of](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/10420/due-to-versus-as-a-result-of)

Comment: @Chenmunka I don't think the linked question is related with this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Don't we need" may come off as you passive aggressively telling your boss to do it in the same way a spouse may say to their partner, "Don't we need to take out the trash?" as a way to tell that partner to take out the trash.  If you are going to put the question, be clear about who it is would update the chart?  Also, don't pose the question as a negative "don't" but a positive "do," or an even softer "should."

> "I have updated the data in chart A. Should [name] update the data in chart
>   B, too?"

Be specific about who will have the responsibility of updating the data in chart B, whether it be you, IT, the secretary, or even your boss.  Although, I must warn, most bosses do not like it when subordinates try to delegate tasks upwardly to them.

Answer (score 1):

It would be more natural to respond ""I have updated the data in chart A. **Do they need to be updated in chart B as well?**".

The way it's written at the moment assumes that the data *has* to be updated.

[Technically speaking, 'data' is plural; 'datum' is the singular]

Comment: *Do they*, not *does they*.

Comment: @StoneyB: that's because I changed the "it" to "they" but forgot to change the "Does" to "Do".

Comment: I'd add that if you work in a field where data is routinely used as a singular noun, using data as a plural can come across as pretentious.

Comment: In the US, in non-academic settings data commonly is used with the singular. If you said "datum" people would consider it odd. There is no consensus whether data is plural or singular, or at least there is a difference between North American English and British English. Not sure where the Aussies fall. http://www.economist.com/blogs/graphicdetail/2012/07/point-information

Comment: I am a doctoral candidate, and one of the first things written in my course texts is that the plural of datum is data. I did write "Technically speaking".

Comment: And if you decide to leave academia when you graduate, treating data as plural in the US will make people look at you funny. Don't even think about using datum in an email to your boss. The question isn't very clear about the context, but it sounds more corporate than academic to me.